# C# Threading for a pipeline

Tags: c#, multithreading, pipelining

I'm currently creating a pipeline for my asm simulator. I'm to do this with multithreading. Currently I have four threads which correspond to each Fetch, Decode, Execute, and Write Back. I'm confused about how to code a correct pipeline. Here is some of my code:

```
private void Fetch()
{
    while(_continue)
    {
        fetchEvent.WaitOne();
        if (!_continue) break;
        lock (irLock)
        {
            try
            {
                // Do stuff to fetch instruction...

                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e) { Err = "Segmentation Fault at Line " + _pc.ToString(); }
                catch (Exception e) { Err = e.Message + "Line " + _pc.ToString(); }
                _pc++;

                GiveTurnTo(2); // used these 2 lines to handle mutual exclusion
                WaitTurn(1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Decode()
    {
        while (_continue)
        {
            decodeEvent.WaitOne();
            if (!_continue) break;

            lock (irLock)
            {
                WaitTurn(2);
                Console.WriteLine("decode works");
                GiveTurnTo(1);
            }


        }
    }

    private void Execute()
    {
        while (_continue)
        {
            exeEvent.WaitOne();
            if (!_continue) break;

            lock (irLock)
            {
                //WaitTurn(3);
                Console.WriteLine("Am I, execute, getting a turn?");
                // GiveTurnTo(4);
            }

        }

    }

    private void WriteBack()
    {
        while (_continue)
        {
            wbEvent.WaitOne();
            if (!_continue) break;

            lock (irLock)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Am I, Write Back, getting a turn?");
                //GiveTurnTo(1);
                // WaitTurn(4);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I use this method to run a cycle with a button click:

```
public void nextInstruction()
{
    fetchEvent.Set();
    decodeEvent.Set();
    exeEvent.Set();
    wbEvent.Set();
}
I was thinking of changing nextInstruction() to this:

public void nextInstruction()
{
    fetchEvent.Set();
}
```

Where each button click will always start with Fetch. After that I thought maybe I could place a set event within the Fetch method to call the next part in the cycle (Decode) and do the same for the following methods. I would end up with something like this:

```
private void Fetch()
{
    while(_continue)
    {
        // Do stuff....
        decodeEvent.Set();
    }
}

private void Decode()
{
    while (_continue)
    {
        // Do stuff...
        exeEvent.Set();
    }
}

private void Execute()
{
    while (_continue)
    {
        // Do stuff...
        wbEvent.Set();
    }
}
private void WriteBack()
{
    while (_continue)
    {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Instead of leaving those set events out in the open, I think they should be activated by some sort of logic, but I don't know what kind of logic. Maybe they could be activated by a button click. That would allow me to control when an instruction is passed down the cycle. In theory, I think this could give me the structure of a pipeline. Can anyone provide any input on this? Can this be accomplished with just Auto Reset Events?

If you look at the first block of code I gave, you can see I tried using a lock, but that made it so only one thread could run at a time. I want to make it so that it follows the format of `Fetch0, {Decode0, Fetch1}, {Execute0, Decode1, Fetch3},...` and so on. Are locks a necessity in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Threads are not appropriate for this. You are doing too little work per step before you put the thread to sleep. A better way to simulate it would be just have a single thread doing each of the steps ***in reverse order***, this will ripple the work down the system just like the real system.

```
public void nextInstruction()
{
    WriteBack();
    Execute();
    Decode();
    Fetch();
}
```

---

To help understand why I process them in reverse order take a look at how my system works as we call it repeatedly.

- Call 1

  1. `WriteBack()` does nothing, its input buffer is empty.
  2. `Execute()` does nothing, its input buffer is empty.
  3. `Decode()` does nothing, its input buffer is empty.
  4. `Fetech()` Grabs the **1st** instruction and puts it in to `Decode()`'s input buffer.
- Call 2

  1. `WriteBack()` does nothing, its input buffer is empty.
  2. `Execute()` does nothing, its input buffer is empty.
  3. `Decode()` Grabs the fetched **1st** instruction from it's input buffer, places the decoded instruction in to `Execute()`'s input buffer.
  4. `Fetech()` Grabs the **2nd** instruction and puts it in to `Decode()`'s input buffer.
- Call 3

  1. `WriteBack()` does nothing, its input buffer is empty.
  2. `Execute()` Grabs the decoded **1st** instruction from its input buffer, processes it, then places the result in to `WriteBack()`'s input buffer.
  3. `Decode()` Grabs the fetched **2nd** instruction from its input buffer, processes it, then places the decoded instruction in to `Execute()`'s input buffer.
  4. `Fetech()` Grabs the **3rd** instruction and puts it in to `Decode()`'s input buffer.
- Call 4

  1. `WriteBack()` Grabs the processed **1st** value from its input buffer and writes it back to the memory store.
  2. `Execute()` Grabs the decoded **2nd** instruction from its input buffer, processes it, then places the result in to `WriteBack()`'s input buffer.
  3. `Decode()` Grabs the fetched **3rd** instruction from itss input buffer, processes it, then places the decoded instruction in to `Execute()`'s input buffer.
  4. `Fetech()` Grabs the **4th** instruction and puts it in to `Decode()`'s input buffer.
- Call 5

  1. `WriteBack()` Grabs the processed **2nd** value from its input buffer and writes it back to the memory store.
  2. `Execute()` Grabs the decoded **3rd** instruction from its input buffer, processes it, then places the result in to `WriteBack()`'s input buffer.
  3. `Decode()` Grabs the fetched **4th** instruction from itss input buffer, processes it, then places the decoded instruction in to `Execute()`'s input buffer.
  4. `Fetech()` Grabs the **5th** instruction and puts it in to `Decode()`'s input buffer.
- Call 6

  1. `WriteBack()` Grabs the processed **3rd** value from its input buffer and writes it back to the memory store.
  2. `Execute()` Grabs the decoded **4th** instruction from its input buffer, processes it, then places the result in to `WriteBack()`'s input buffer.
  3. `Decode()` Grabs the fetched **5th** instruction from itss input buffer, processes it, then places the decoded instruction in to `Execute()`'s input buffer.
  4. `Fetech()` Grabs the **6th** instruction and puts it in to `Decode()`'s input buffer.
- ect.

See it takes 4 calls before the pipeline is full, this is what happens in real life, it takes more cycles to get the first instruction from `Fetch` to `WriteBack` however the time period between instructions coming out of the pipeline is a lot shorter in comparision.

Now looking at your old system you can see you actually don't ever fill your pipeline, a single instruction can go right through all of the stages in a single simulation step.

- Call 1

  1. `Fetech()` Grabs the **1st** instruction and puts it in to `Decode()`'s input buffer.
  2. `Decode()` Grabs the fetched **1st** instruction from its input buffer, processes it, then places the decoded instruction in to `Execute()`'s input buffer.
  3. `Execute()` Grabs the decoded **1st** instruction from its input buffer, processes it, then places the result in to `WriteBack()`'s input buffer.
  4. `WriteBack()` Grabs the processed **1st** value from its input buffer and writes it back to the memory store.
- Call 2

  1. `Fetech()` Grabs the **2nd** instruction and puts it in to `Decode()`'s input buffer.
  2. `Decode()` Grabs the fetched **2nd** instruction from its input buffer, processes it, then places the decoded instruction in to `Execute()`'s input buffer.
  3. `Execute()` Grabs the decoded **2nd** instruction from its input buffer, processes it, then places the result in to `WriteBack()`'s input buffer.
  4. `WriteBack()` Grabs the processed **2nd** value from its input buffer and writes it back to the memory store.

In a single call our instruction went from fetched to written back before we even could fetch the 2nd instruction

Comment: I understand what you're talking about, but this is for an assigment and each cycle should be executed with its own thread. I had an idea to keep instructions from being completed in one call. To do this I want to have each cycle call the next (except write back) AutoResetEvent every time the button is clicked. If those cycles aren't ready to be called then they won't be. What do you think?

Comment: You have given too general a description for me to have any thoughts on it. Try it out, if it does not work go ahead and ask a new question about what did not work.

Answer (score 1):

A pipeline is a process that raises events sync or async. Observers are registerrd with the pipeline to be notified for these events. The pipeline stores the state to allow observers to work with the state. In the case of async events, you will have to ensure synchronization takes place around the state, as well as callbacks to know when the thread has completed or ready for work. Here is a rough high level example of using a pipeline:

```
public class OnFetchEvent : AsyncEvent {}
public class OnDecodeEvent : AsyncEvent {}
public class OnExecuteEvent : AsyncEvent {}
public class OnWritebackEvent : AsyncEvent {}

public class FetchObserver : Observer,
   IObserve<OnFetchEvent>
{
   public void OnEvent(OnFetchEvent @event)
   {
      ....do some stuff

      // raise the next event
      RaiseEvent<OnDecodeEvent>(); 
   }
}

public class Pipeline
{
   public void RaiseEvent<TEvent>()
   {
      if (typeof(TEvent) is AsyncEvent)
        ...create thread and raise the event which will notify the appropriate 
           observers of the event in the newly created thread
   }

  }
```

Usage:

```
pipeline.RegisterObserver<FetchObserver>()
  .AndObserver<DecodeObserver>()
  .AndObserver<ExecuteObserver>()
  .AndObserver<WriteBackObserver>();

pipeline.RaiseEvent<OnFetchEvent>();
```

This will handle one cycle. Events are raised async (which means the observers will be executed per thread). To have multiple cycles, you need to start the pipeline async (its own thread). And call the pipeline RaiseEvent as required. I hope this provides some high level approach of making use of a pipeline using threads.

Comment: In the situation you describe you want to spawn 4 threads for a task. This is not same as working with a pipeline. In that scenario you would need for 4 queues to move the work from one thread to another thread via enqueue and dequeue, where the threads monitor the queues for work and handle each task in a queue synchronously.